# JQuery UI functions are not working locally

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, plugins

I got the following JS, CSS and HTML files running

> http://jsbin.com/esubag/2/edit

I have a JQuery UI `.hide('bounce');` function running in the JS file. It works fine on JSBin but, when I runs it locally no JQuery UI functions execute! I have include the UI plugin both locally and via Google API just to be sure, as you can probably see! But I can't sort this problem out!

Comment: Any javascript error in console locally? I've tried your code on my local computer and everything seems ok

Comment: check the js console and leave only one jquery ui

Comment: Don't load jQuery and jQuery UI twice and check your path to animations.js.

Comment: Can you please try to use some browser extension (such as Firebug), and check that your scripts are loaded properly ? 
Like @j08691 said, make sure you're not loading multiple time the jQuery or jQuery UI libraries

Comment: Hi there thanks for your help. I don't know if this was the solution but I had a virus that was conflicting with all my browsers! Once I removed that it worked! Claro was the name of the virus. – Vishal Sakaria just now edit

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$(document).ready(function()  
{  
     $('div#intro_title').hide('bounce');   
});
```

With just:

```
$('div#intro_title').hide('bounce');
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for your help. I don't know if this was the solution but I had a virus that was conflicting with all my browsers! Once I removed that it worked! Claro was the name of the virus.

Answer (score -1):

Do you see when running locally the net traffic(in firebug or any browser web dev tools) to get the scripts. Or this might be a problem of caching. First try and do a ctrl+f5 to refresh all the scripts. If you see exactly the same javascript that you have in the JS bin and it is still not working then their might be another problem maybe just with that particular browser you are using maybe try another one.